# Vaadin DropDown/Select/Spinner best practice?

Tags: java, vaadin, dropdown

I am looking at the Vaadin components and it seems like the "favoured" Select-component in Vaadin does not run on indexing.

Using this code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("A");
    
    Select<String> select = new Select<>();
    select.setItems(list);
```

So when I have the following list:

1. A
2. B
3. A

And I choose the third option, A, it would appear as the first option, also A, in the list. Is there a Vaadin component or library with java implementation which runs on indexed values? or has there been a workaround.

Comment: What are your indexed values? Are you talking about a java `List`? What kind of data is in the list? You would have to be specific, of what data you want to represent.

Comment: I added the code now. I missed it in the first iteration, sorry.

Comment: You would have to use distinct values (e.g. enums or tuples with index and value) and then use a label generator to change the text shown to the user. And unless the numbers are part of those labels I'd find it very confustion to have multiple things with the same name but different order - but since you are hiding the domain, that might be just fine for your use-case.

Comment: String literals like "A" are coming from the Java String Pool - if you have `String first = "cat";` and `String second = "cat";`, both variables will be pointing to the same String object. So your test code is too trivial - you must use unique objects. See more here: https://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would the end user distinguish those identical options?

The `Select` component relies on the `equals` and `hashCode` methods to distinguish items. In your case, the two strings are equal to each other, and as such they are the same from the component's point of view.

So if you have a valid use case for this, you will have to pass items where `equals` is properly implemented for the use case.

There are several ways to do this: making a custom class, passing in a map of values, passing in an enum etc. In all cases you will probably want to use a custom item label generator.

With a map, it would look something like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put(1, "A");
values.put(2, "B");
values.put(3, "A");

Select<Integer> select = new Select<>();
select.setItems(values.keySet());
select.setItemLabelGenerator(values::get);

add(select);
```

Or with an enum, as cfrick suggested:

```
enum Option {
    FIRST_A("A"), B("B"), SECOND_A("A");

    private final String name;

    Option(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

...

Select<Option> select = new Select<>();
select.setItems(Option.values());
select.setItemLabelGenerator(Option::getName);

add(select);
```

Comment: It's not that there is a valid case for it to be "A,B,A", but since some lists are made by the users themselves. User error can happen, so the code is necessary for my current project. Thank you (and the other respondents as well) so much.